# Hiding a nested div with an animation when hovered

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

[Navbar link](https://www.experimonkey.com/monkey/devel/)

I've been considering making some changes to the navbar for a kids' website I'm designing (never mind if it's user-friendly/attractive at this point), and thought about using icons that, when hovered, display some text to the right (with a transition to the max-width property). In order for the scrolling between icons to be more intuitive, I had to make it so that when the exposed text is hovered (`.hidden`), the text goes back into hiding (otherwise when a user tries to point to the next icon, all of a sudden the text closes and they end up pointing to a different icon).

This almost works, but when the text disappears, things start to get wonky if the user has their cursor near the division between the text and the icon. I am guessing it's because the text is trying to animate both ways at the same time (i.e. as soon as `.hidden` disappears, the cursor is now hovering over the `.nav-link` again).

Here, `.hidden` is the text that appears to the right of the icon. `.nav-link` is the parent div that includes the image icon as well as the `.hidden` div.

```css
.hidden {
  max-width: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  font-size: .9rem;
  font-family: 'Lato';
  padding: 0px;
}

.hidden:hover {
  max-width: 0px !important;
  transition: all .3s !important;
  padding: 0px !important;
}

.nav-link:hover>.hidden {
  padding-left: 2px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  max-width: 400px;
  transition: all .7s ease-in-out;
  transition-delay: .2s;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <a class="nav-link " href="/games">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <img alt="games icon" src='/img/global/icons/icon-games.jpg' width='40'>
      <span class='hidden align-middle'>Flash Games</span>
    </li>
  </a>   
  <a class="nav-link " href="/quizzes">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <img alt="images icon" src='/img/global/icons/icon-quizzes.jpg' width='40'>
      <span class='hidden align-middle'>Science Quizzes</span>
    </li>
  </a>     
</ul>
```

Comment: please post your html

Comment: I'll try to post a segment of it. I tried to post as a snippet earlier, but was having difficulty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks horrible, but for a simple fix change

```
.nav-link, .nav-item {
  min-width: 3rem;
}
```

to

```
.nav-link,.nav-item{
  margin-left:3px;
}
.nav-link:first-child,.nav-item:first-child{
   margin-left:0;
}
```

Learn how to use your developer tools.

Comment: This worked well, thank you. (I agree, the code is a mess.). I think I chose width because I was concerned that margin would affect the mobile layout, but I can see that I am going to have to tinker with that anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Like it was pointed out, you've got numerous issues in your semantic structure and syntax that wouldn't pass a code review but since you're tinkering. You could transition the width, or play around with animations too.. Cheers

```css
.special-nav {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.special-nav li a {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 2rem;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  border: silver 1px solid;
  transition: background-color .25s ease;
}
.special-nav li a span {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-left: .35rem;
  width: 0;
}
.special-nav li a img {
  width: 40;
}
.special-nav li a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}
.special-nav li a:hover span {
  animation: grow 1s forwards;
}

@keyframes grow {
  to {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul class="special-nav">
  <li>
    <a href="/games">
      <img alt="games icon" src="https://via.placeholder.com/30">
      <span>Flash Games</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="/quizzes">
      <img alt="images icon" src="https://via.placeholder.com/30">
      <span>Science Quizzes</span>
    </a>
  </li> 
</ul>
```